# Is there a word meaning "of or relating to objects?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, objects

The closest I've found is *objectual*, but depending on the source, that may not be an actual word.

For example, if I were to refer to an author's use of symbolism via objects I would say something like:

> *The author is fond of ____ symbolism.*

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence with a blank where the word should go?

Comment: @KristinaLopez For example, if I were to refer to an author's use of symbolism via objects: "____ symbolism."

Comment: If the objects are artifacts (objects made by man), you could use *artifactual*.

Comment: With regard to your example, what about "actualised symbolism"?

Comment: "Concrete" might do the trick here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that nouns can modify other nouns in so-called *[noun premodifier constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)*, you might just go with ***object***, as in

> *The author is fond of **object symbolism**.*

Here are some examples where the phrase "object symbolism" is used:

> This volume offers a number of new insights into the use of object symbolism
>
> [*Romanticism and the Object*, by L. Peer](https://books.google.com/books?id=jaS_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22object%20symbolism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi49biW3JXRAhUJ24MKHVvDCOU4ChDoAQgpMAM#v=onepage&q=%22object%20symbolism%22&f=false)

and

> A philosopher who has considered object symbolism in a particularly profound way is Gaston Bachelard
>
> [*Symbolic Action Theory and Cultural Psychology*, by Ernest E. Boesch](https://books.google.com/books?id=5IZfBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT249&dq=%22object%20symbolism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4gIrD3JXRAhVr5IMKHZMZCygQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22object%20symbolism%22&f=false)

Further, here are some relatively common phrases in which the noun *object* modifies another noun:

1. *object recognition*
2. *object knowledge*
3. *object permanence*
4. *object manipulation*
5. *object work*